# Toggle div except on anchor click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onclick

I would like to toggle my `div` on clicking anywhere on the parent `div` except when an `anchor` element is clicked. So for example, if I click the first text in my example, I would like it to toggle but on the second text in my example, I don't want it to toggle.

**[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lwaxnmoc/1/)**

I have tried using `!key.relatedTarget.tagName == 'a'` but I keep getting `undefined`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the above answer.

For a JQuery way of doing it;

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.panel').on('click', function(e){
      if(e.target.id != 'test_description'){
        $('.description').toggle();
      }
  });
})
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lwaxnmoc/4/)

Or specifically for an A-element;

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.panel').on('click', function(e){
        var target = $( e.target );
        if ( !target.is("a") ) {
            $(this).find('.description').toggle();
        }
  });
})
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xf5300qa/1/)

For javascript only:

```
        if ( target.get(0).tagName.toLowerCase() != 'a' ) {
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this solely in JS? and not jquery?

Comment: There is, updated my post with the javascript way of determining whether the target element is an anchor or not.

Answer (score 1):

You should checking event target:

```
function show_description(key) {
  if( !$( event.target ).is( "a" ) )
    {
        $('#' + key + '_description').slideToggle(100);
    }
}
```

**[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lwaxnmoc/2/)**